# Better way of incrementing a date month?

Tags: python

I have a date as an int like so for example: `201805` I'd like to have a way where I can give the start date and it'll return back the next date, in this example: 201806. Currently, I have this solution:

```
def incrementDate(startdate):
    try:
        newdate = dt.datetime.strptime(str(startdate + 1), "%Y%m")
            return str(newdate.year) + newdate.strftime('%m')
        except:
            newdate = dt.datetime.strptime(str(startdate), "%Y%m")
            return int(str(newdate.year + 1) + "01")
```

Is this a good way of going about this or is there a simple better way?

Comment: You shouldn't use try/except for control flow

Comment: @9769953 Sorry about that, startdate is an int I corrected the question

Comment: @user2896120 do you have the date also ? because it seems that you only have the year and the month

Comment: You have a string that *looks* like an `int`; I assume `"201812"` should increment to `"201901"`, not `"201813"`.

Comment: @chepner not according to the code.

Comment: @9769953 Just updated the question again, thanks!

Comment: If you add the line `print(type(startdate))` before the `try...except` in your function, what is the console output from the print statement?

Comment: It still has one part return an int, the other a str. Doesn't matter for the core of the question, but to avoid confusion.

Comment: @9769953 I should rephrase: the start date is a label *encoded* as an `int`, but itsn't the `int` itself that is of interest, but its representation in base 10.

Comment: In that case, you're definitely better off passing a `str` in the first place, and skip the whole integer thing in the first place. Unless you have no control over your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something using relativedelta:

Your first step will be to install the package dateutil:

```
pip install dateutil
```

Then you will be able to use it:

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
print(datetime.datetime.strptime(str(201805), "%Y%m") + relativedelta(months=1))
```

Or a string:

```
print((datetime.datetime.strptime(str(201805), "%Y%m") + relativedelta(months=1)).strftime("%Y%m"))
```

Note: relativedelta comes from a separate package called 'dateutil' ([here for the details](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html)). It includes notably a nice way to add month / days / year .. without creating a custom function.

Comment: Doesn't this print a date instead of an int that looks something like: "201801" ?

Comment: you can use str() if you want to have it a a str - I can add it.

Comment: It will still print in this format: '2018-02-01 00:00:00' which is not the format i want, i want it to look like "201801"

Comment: @user2896120 Why did you accept the answer if it doesn't do what you want? Besides, shouldn't it print "201806", instead of "201801"?

Comment: I have updated it. Now it will give you a str format with the same structure as you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def incrementDate(startdate):
    cur_date = datetime.strptime(str(startdate), '%Y%m')
    next_date = cur_date + timedelta(days=32)
    return datetime.strftime(next_date, '%Y%m')


print(incrementDate(201806))  # 201807
print(incrementDate(201812))  # 201901
```

Comment: By adding 32 days, you're not only changing the month but also the day.

Comment: Yes, but is just used internally in the function to calculate the next month. Never exposed to the caller. And since we return a year/month string it doesn't affect the result.

Comment: But if we use it around 30 times on the same value, we'll add two months, at some point.

Comment: You would be right if `incrementDate` returned a `datetime` object. But in this case it returns a date string in the format `201906`, `199802`.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, if your input is really an integer that represents a 4 digit year folowed by a 2 digit month, then you can increment the month without any string or datetime conversions.

```
d = 201812

y, m = d // 100, d % 100
if m == 12:
    y += 1
    m = 1
else:
    m +=1

d = y * 100 + m

print(d)
# 201806
```

Answer (score 0):

The `replace()` method fron the `datetime` objects allows you to update a parameter from the `datetime` object:

```py
import datetime

today = datetime.datetime.now()

current_month = today.month
year = today.year

# Check for december
if current_month < 12:
  next_month = current_month + 1
else:
  next_month = 1
  year += 1

today= today.replace(month = next_month, year = year )
```

[Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#time-objects)

To put in in your function:

```py
import datetime

def increment_date(startdate):
  date = datetime.strptime(str(startdate), '%Y%m')
  current_month = date .month
  year = date .year

  # Check for december
  if current_month < 12:
    next_month = current_month + 1
  else:
    next_month = 1
    year += 1

  return date .replace(month = next_month, year = year )
```

Comment: Oh yes! 
Edited to check if December.